# How to install latest calibre (any package) on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, apt, versions, calibre

If I am installing [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) with `apt-get`, it installs version 1.25

```
# sudo apt-show-versions calibre
calibre:all/trusty 1.25.0+dfsg-1build1 uptodate
```

while it's current version is 2.6.

Is it possible to install newer calibre, staying with `apt-get`?

Answer (score 11):

Calibre's website advises against uses the distribution's package for this reason (It's typically outdated/buggy). And I didn't see any repositories with updated calibre, so `apt-get` wasn't looking like the best option.

You can use `wget`, though, to download & install the binaries right from Calibre. Calibre's site instructs you to paste the following command into the terminal to install or update:

```
sudo -v && 
  wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py | 
  sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"
```

Source: http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

I just did it, and it worked perfectly. And when Calibre tells you there's a new version, you should be able to paste that same thing into the terminal to update. Or you can write a script to do it automatically.

Is there a reason you wanted to stick with `apt-get`, other than being familiar with it?

Comment: "Is there a reason you wanted to stick with apt-get" .. the obvious one: `apt-get` handles most other updates. This adds one more place to (manually) check for updates.

Comment: Ah, right. Of course. I guess you could use a script that automatically checks if the version is outdated and updates if it is.

Comment: "Is there a reason you wanted to stick with apt-get". Well, piping unchecked web content into sudo may make one a bit nervous.

Comment: @Evpok, they have an non-sudo option: ["You can also do an "isolated" install that only touches files inside the installation directory and does not need to be run as root, like this:"](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) `wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.py | python -c "import sys; main=lambda x,y:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main('~/calibre-bin', True)"`

Comment: calibre 3.19 doesn't start on ubuntu 14.04 unless you set two qt variables QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1 QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=1 as explained here https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=288152

Comment: @StevenC.Howell, I see this command has been changed now to: `wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.sh | sh /dev/stdin install_dir=~/calibre-bin isolated=y`. Anyway, does it offer the same functionality as a sudo install?

Comment: @geras, typically the only difference between a root (sudo) vs unprivileged installation for a program like this will be what users on the system can use it.  I would have to double check which I have, so I cannot say certainly what you should expect.  Regardless, I would be surprised if they do not behave the same.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell, and how could I uninstall this programme if I installed it this way?

Comment: @geras all you would need to do is delete the folder it installed in.  Linux installs are typically MUCH simpler than on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the version mentioned by `apt-get` is the latest version in the repositories that are known to it. If you are able to find a newer repo for Calibre, you could add it so `apt-get` can look for the packages and install it. But please make sure it's a secure/trusted repository!

Edit: Here is a [list on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=calibre) with some repositories, but since the official site doesn't mention one itself (at least, I couldn't find it) they're not offical.